# Mac App Store Automatically Cancels Downloading Xcode

Tags: mac, macos, xcode, mac-appstore

When I try to download Xcode from the MAS, the download automatically stops after several minutes.

It's not because of internet problems because the internet was working fine at the same time as the download.  I have tried multiple times but still get the same result.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You need at least 20GB of free space to download Xcode.  Do you have enough available space?